# Mailgun curl command is not sending emails

Tags: curl, mailgun

The issue that I'm running into is that the example curl command that mailgun provides is not sending an email. This is what it looks like once I substitute in my values

```
curl -s --user 'api:dfjkdjksan-api-keyasdfjkj' \
    sandbox33380083kdsomedomain39dks.mailgun.org \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@sandbox33380083kdsomedomain39dks.mailgun.org>' \
    -F to='example@gmail.com' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
```

This command prints something like "Mailgun API" to the console, but the email doesn't appear in the inbox. The to email (`example@gmail.com`) is registered on the mailgun website

When I try out the test mailer, I get this status infinately, when the timer runs out, it just starts over.

[image]

Comment: Failure of an external service is probably not a programming question suitable for here. Anyhow, what about the spam folder? Mailgun is a mass mailer, they easily end up in blacklists.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It wasn't showing up in there either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `/messages` to the end of your domain so it's

`curl -s --user 'api:dfjkdjksan-api-keyasdfjkj' \ sandbox33380083kdsomedomain39dks.mailgun.org/messages`

Also if you're using GoDaddy, make the domain for most of you mx and txt records to be just the subdomain like `mg` instead of `mg.yourdomain.com`